# Liferay 7.2: Open asset publisher viewURL in a Display Page Template

Tags: themes, liferay-7.2

I am using Liferay 7.2. I want to display the viewURL link of an asset publisher in a Display Page Templates page. I couldn’t solve the problem. After searching, I realized that this problem can be solved in three ways:

**Method 1:**
1- As and admin, in Web Content>Structures create a structure (News Article) and make a Template for that structure.
2- Create page A and add an asset publisher. In this asset publisher: In Asset Selection choose Web Content Article  as Asset Type and choose News Article as sub structure. In Display Setting  tab choose View in Context as Asset Link Behavior.
3-In Site Builder>Pages create a Display Page Template (page B). Edit it and add an asset publisher similar to page A. However, in page B, in Configuration of asset publisher, in Display Settings choose Show Full Content as Asset Link Behavior and tick Set as the Default Asset Publisher for This Page  and Show only assets with Page B as its display page template.
4-Create some News Article. In Display Page Template section, choose Specific Display Page Template and Page B.

In page A, everything is OK. However, when I click on ViewURL of an asset entry, it will redirect to page B. But, in asset publisher section of page B, no results is shown (There are no results.). Means that the chosen asset of page A is not shown in Display Page Template of page B.

**Method 2:** 
Maybe the simplest method is editing Display Page Template (page B) in Section Builder>Content Display add Display Page Template. However, as stated in this issue , the display page content section only shows the summary and no style can be shown. Maybe it is necessary to edit abstract.jsp file. But, I don’t know how to do this.

**Method 3:**
Create a Widget Template and add it to page B. The article data of the selected asset can be obtained from the URL. However, I couldn’t get the data of the selected article.

I  appreciate for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

An Asset Publisher instantiated in a Display Page Template won't show the page Web Content. One way to show an Web Content in a Display Page Template, is to instantiate a Fragment and map the Web Content fields to it, as shown [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028820352-Display-Page-Template-Example).

So, to solve your problem, you would need to change Page's B Asset Publisher to one or more Fragments, and map your News Article fields to them.

You could also map the Web Content to your own custom Fragmets, using [Fragments `lfr-editable` fields](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/site-building/developer-guide/reference/fragments/fragment-specific-tags-reference.html)

```html
<lfr-editable id="unique-id" type="text">
   This is editable text!
</lfr-editable>
```

Another way is to get the Web Content Java Object instance inside a Freemarker (a Fragment, Widget Template, Web Content Template, etc) with [this](https://gist.github.com/marcosblandim/2a514a826989655d63ef88f7efb697b8) snippet **(only works for 7.3+)**

```
${Request.INFO_ITEM}
```